# any python module can support enumerate 2 lists and do the "cross multiplication"?

Tags: python, list, combinations, emulation

I often write below snippets in daily works,

```
res = []
a = ["A","B","C","D"]
b = [1,2,3,4]
for _a in a:
    for _b in b:
        res.append((_a,_b))
# or be more simple 
#[(_a,_b) for _a in a for _b in b]

[('A', 1),
 ('A', 2),
 ('A', 3),
 ('A', 4),
 ('B', 1),
 ('B', 2),
 ('B', 3),
 ('B', 4),
 ('C', 1),
 ('C', 2),
 ('C', 3),
 ('C', 4),
 ('D', 1),
 ('D', 2),
 ('D', 3),
 ('D', 4)]
```

May I know

1. if there's any special term on computer area for this kind of action?
2. if there's a way, e.g. a python module can do this job? for example I have 20 lists need list all of the combination? can itertools do it?

Thanks

Comment: the term I believe you're looking for is permutations. but I'm not really sure what you're after.

Comment: I think the itertools can do this kinds of jobs, but I missed itertools.product can accept args already, thanks grep and others for their answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.product` is exactly what you need:

```
>>> list(itertools.product("ABCD", "1234"))
[('A', '1'), ('A', '2'), ('A', '3'), ('A', '4'), ('B', '1'),
('B', '2'), ('B', '3'), ('B', '4'), ('C', '1'), ('C', '2'),
('C', '3'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '1'), ('D', '2'), ('D', '3'),
('D', '4')]
```

Comment: thanks for reminder the product can accept multi-args, the document sample is product('ABCD', repeat=2) so I missed it

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
res = list(itertools.product(a, b))
```